# how to install xgboost in python step by step?

Tags: python, git, shell

i am having problem in installing xgboost in python on a windows machine, one reason is my limited knowledge of shell and command prompt .

now in my command prompt (windows+x) i wrote

`git clone https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost.git`

but it did not run saying git is not defined

then since i have git shell too installed when i was downloading github desktop i wrote the same code

```
git clone https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost.git
```

and then followed up with `cd xgboost; make; cd wrapper; python.py setup install --user` but now it is saying ***make*** is not defined . please help i am trying to learn some of these command prompt things but i find it hard :(

Comment: let me guess is it windows?

Comment: oh ya i am sorry i will edit

Comment: do you have pip? It would save so much effort and time because you will need to install many other things and struggle with many errors. If you install pip it will just be `pip install xgboost`. Look at the readme here: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/tree/master/python-package

Comment: yaa i have tried with pip but it shows error i checked and pip don't work for xgboost

Comment: The url I wrote also has how to compile on windows using visual studio. Search for "For windows users" and there is a link to a tutorial.